# Angular2 Update my clock every second

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on something in `Angular2` and I need to update my `clock` every second.
I just don't know how I can make my `clock` as it works now, to update every second.

this is my COMPONENT.TS File:

```
         import { Component } from '@angular/core';
         import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

         @Component({
            selector: 'page-header',
            templateUrl: './pageheader.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['./pageheader.component.css']
         })

         export class PageHeaderComponent {

              Housestyle = 'Dit is de huisstyle'

              Clock = Date.now();
         }
```

And this is my HTML:

```
       <div id="container">
            <div id="left">{{Housestyle}}</div>
            <div id="right">{{Clock | date:'HH:mm'}}</div>
            <div id="center"></div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     import { Component } from '@angular/core';
     import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

     @Component({
        selector: 'page-header',
        templateUrl: './pageheader.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./pageheader.component.css']
     })

     export class PageHeaderComponent {

          Housestyle = 'Dit is de huisstyle'

          Clock = Date.now();

          public ngOnInit() {
            setInterval(() => {
              this.Clock = Date.now();
            }, 1000);
          }
     }
```

and also add `seconds` in your filter in the template

`<div id="right">{{Clock | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</div>`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! 
It works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Use an interval.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
    Clock = Date.now();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help!